# Software for importing lat,lon and displaying Mercator projection

Tags: database, data-visualization, display, geography, geometry

Are there any software [Ideally free] out there which I can import latitudes and longitudes of areas and it displays the [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) of those points? To make the task even easier I must say I am highly flexible in terms of feeding the data into the suggested software and I can convert the latitude and longitude into whatever format the suggested software supports. For instance I can even convert all these latitudes and longitudes into Geography points or whatever supported format the software requires. All I care is displaying the Mercator projection.

Currently I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to view the projection for displaying =< 5000 locations but I cant view more than 5000 objects:

[image]